# Помогите обработать ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует код:

```
litle = 1
a = 'One'
if litle==1:
   litle-=1
   with open('shot_001.txt','r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
      fr = list(f)
      print(fr)
      if fr.index('\ufeff' +a + '\n') == 0:
          print('Это первый индекс')
      else:
          print('Первый индекс')
```

Его задача это вывод сообщения, если в текстовом файле в котором находятся данные типа:

```
One
1
Two
2
```

Стоит отметить что `'One'` и `'Two'` могут меняться.
Если `'One'` находится на первой строчке, то выводится одно сообщение, но он так же может находиться на третьей и тогда выводится другое сообщение. Но когда `a` меняется на `Two`, то выдается ошибка:

> ```
>    if fr.index('\ufeff' +a + '\n') == 0:
>    ValueError: '\ufeffTwo\n' is not in list
> ```

Прошу помощи, что бы обработать или же убрать это ошибку. Спасибо.

Comment: Используйте `if ... in fr` конструкцию

Comment: Уважаемый ТС. Объясните что означает конструкция "if litle==1:
litle-=1" записанная БЕЗ ОТСУПОВ, так как в приведенном примере?

Comment: @passant извеняюсь, не заметил, исправил

Comment: Попробуйте поставить параметр  encoding = 'utf-8-sig'

Comment: @passant Я если честно очень удивлен, так как это помогло, но я погуглил и толком не понял что делает добавление 'sig', если не сложно в двух словах можете описать? Можете написать ответ, я отмечу как верный, если вам это конечно интересно. Спасибо.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет utf-8 c `'\ufeff'`? Никакое. Какое дело имеет `litle` (Little Endian) с utf-8? Никакое. Обе относятся к utf-16.

Comment: *«Стоит отметить что 'One' и 'Two' могут меняться...»* - значит в **файле**, не в (плохой) программе, как вы это сделали.

Comment: *«Существует код...»* - значит, это не ваш код. Хороший совет: Не занимайтесь этим странным, очевидно неправильным кодом, даже не зная, что он хочет делать.

Comment: @MarianD 1: как переменная может иметь отношение к кодировке? Какая разница какую мне кодировку тут использовать если я это делаю просто что бы текст на русском языке нормально выводился,2: в файл приходят данные не зависимо от меня, 3: про существует или не существует код, вообще не понял,я привык так выражаться , и не могу понять почему вы советуете мне бросить этот код, ведь я сюда пришёл не за советами что мне делать а что не делать, вы же шефу не скажите это код отстой ты не прав давай другой. :)

Comment: @RockInMyHead: 1. см. мой ответ, 2. я это предполагал, 3. не стоит тонуть в совершенно неправильном коде, нужно написать другой.

Comment: @MarianD Спасибо за ответ, очень подробно, разобрался, на счёт кода согласен.

Comment: Плохо, что вы не написали, что хотите, чтобы ваша программа точно делала. Я бы написал вам правильный код - и может быть кто-то другой тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш файл очевидно записан в формате с так называемым маркером последовательности байтов (Byte Order Mark- BOM). 
Согласно спецификации Юникода, маркер может стоять только в самом начале файла или потока, т.е. практически не влияет на содержимое файла, а служит лишь своеобразным указателем на то, что файле закодирован в Юникоде. 
Использование этого символа, согласно спецификации Юникод, не является обязательным, тем не менее его достаточно часто используется. В том-же Notepad можно прочесть и легко перекодировать файл в этих вариантах кодировках.

Для чтения таких файлов в параметрах необходимо указывать параметр encoding = 'utf-8-sig'

Answer (score 1):

Ваш файл во внутри такой:

```
\ufeffOne
1
Two
2
```

где последовательность двух байтов`\ufeff` так называемый «BOM».

(Между прочим, мне кажется, что код этой — *принципиально неправильной* — программы назначен для работы с файлом в кодировке UTF-16.)

Значит, полученный из него список `fr` будет `["\ufeffOne\n", "1\n", "Two\n", "2\n"]`.

Теперь получена вами ошибка очевидна:

- `"\ufeffOne\n"` находится в списке `fr` (случай для `a = 'One'`) — нет ошибки, но
- `"\ufeffTwo\n"` **не находится** в списке `fr` (случай для `a = 'Two'`) — **ошибка**

  > ```
  >    if fr.index('\ufeff' +a + '\n') == 0:
  >    ValueError: '\ufeffTwo\n' is not in list
  > ```

  (на русском: «Ошибка значения: `'\ufeffTwo\n'` не находится в списке»)